# Is it possible accessing to only one blob which It depends on another blobs with SAS

Tags: azure

I upload my html5 games to Azure blobs here my list :

[image: ContainerAndBlobs]

I changed games Container status as private and I tried to acess index.html with adding SAS policy to my container , I viewed my html file but I can't see any image or css because It depends on other files but can't allow to access.

I want to acess this game via only on my site so In my opinion ,When I set games container status as public and only index.html blob status private(I don't know Is it available on Azure Storage Explorer) , Can I access this game in my site with SAS ? I know It's a little strange issue but I try to solve it this way so Do you have any idea for accessing and opening this game only on my site ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that because the access policy is applied at the blob container level and all blobs in that blob container inherit that policy. One possible solution would be to move css and images in a public container and keep the blobs you wish to keep private in this container only.

Comment: First of all thanks for answer , But I outsourced all games files so I don't know which documents directory change , All documents are directory based on. If I try to your reccommend , I will have to change All documents directory :( Do you have any idea about it ?

Comment: Without knowing much about your application, one possibility would be have a convention that all images will be in "images" blob container and all css files will be in "css" blob container and the game files will go in "games" blob container and then have your html files in games blob container would reference the css files as ../css/cssfilename.css or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Gaurav, It's very helpful for solving problem , I tried it but It doesn't solve my problem because The main page try to find deployed container's directory :/ So I added [**"base href=.."**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) into my html files and I provided redirect to other container files.Thank you so much all everything.